# Places and Volumes do not open windows anymore

Tags: gnome, window, dock, places

it's strange, for some time now the disks displayed in the dock no longer open windows. The trash icon do.
The same problem has the gnome-extension Places. On a click, I see in the status bar a turning wheel, but no windows opens.
Via the sidebar of the windows I can call the locations without problems. The icons in the dock also show the dot for the open window, but they do not open it themselves.
I am a bit clueless, until recently it all worked without problems.
I tried a reinstall of nautilus (42.2) and the gnome-shell without a change.

It is: Ubuntu 22.04.1 , Gnome 42.4 , Wayland

Thanks for any tip.
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem:
The program digikam installed the package wslu (collection of utilities for the Windows 10 Linux Subsystem) during installation.
After uninstalling this package, Gnome works with the Dock and Places as usual.
Whether digikam needs the package wslu under gnome wayland is not clear to me, but it seems to run.